# Audit Logging skips logging ID of tables with composite-primary key

Tags: grails, audit-trail

I'm implementing [Audit Logging 1.1 Grails Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging?skipRedirect=true) to track the changes to my domain classes midway of our project implementation. These are an example domain object for our scenario:

> Students need to answer questions. A question can ask for a single or a multiple answers.

```
class Question {
    static auditable = true

    Integer id
    String content

    static hasMany = [
        answers: Answer
    ]
}

class Student {
    static auditable = true

    Integer id
    String name

    static hasMany = [
        answers: Answer
    ]
}

class Answer implements Serializable {
    static auditable = true

    Integer sequence
    String value

    static belongsTo = [
        student: Student,
        question: Question
    ]

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ["student", "question", "sequence"]
    }
}
```

Every time I perform insert/updates to any of these tables, the plugin fires an event and logs it to my `AuditLog` table. All `DML` are successfully logged as expected except for the `Answer` table. The problem is that the `PERSISTED_OBJECT_ID` is always null:

```
+----+---+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | … | CLASS_NAME | EVENT_NAME | PERSISTED_OBJECT_ID | PROPERTY_NAME | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE |
+----+---+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| …  | … | Answer     | UPDATE     |                     | value         | A         | B         |
| …  | … | Answer     | UPDATE     |                     | value         | B         | A         |
+----+---+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I tried to include the `logIds = true` config but it still not persisting. Without that column, I cannot identify which `Answer` is updated by whom. I'm expecting that this would be the case of all the composite primary keys domain classes that I have.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 2.x plugin version when my new/oldValue was domain class object. I decided it by overriding toString() method for domain which was saved as value. Try to override toString() for your "student" and "question" domain.

Update:

I didn't use composite key as Id in my project (it seems it's why your persistedObjectId is empty) and also I used 2.x version of plugin. My decision for problems which looks like your, may be it will help you :
I have domains:

```
class Manager {
}

class Customer {
}

class Item {
Manager manager
Customer customer
Item parentItem
BigDecimal qtyOnHand
}
```

I log changes of qtyOnHand and parentItem. With first everything is easy. For second (as  I remember default value will be smth like this: "[id:15]Object123402"):
1. overrided toString()

```
 public String toString() {
    id 
}
```

2. in configurations: logIds = false => plugin writes only id of object

Also I log managerId and customerId using "uri" for it (for simple it will be):

```
def getAuditLogUri = {
    managerId as String
}
```

We can write all in uri and than past in beforeInsert:

```
class Item {
......
def getAuditLogUri = {
    getAuditFields()
}

private Map getAuditFields() {
    return [managerId: manager.id, customerId: customer.id]
}
....
}

class AuditLog{
String actor
String uri
String className
String persistedObjectId
String propertyName
String oldValue
String newValue
String managerId
String customerId
.....
def beforeInsert() {
    getAdditionalFields(uri)
}
private void getAdditionalFields(String fields) {
    Map map = Eval.me(fields)
    managerId = map.managerId
    customerId = map.customerId
}
```

Everything works in my project, I think the it will work the same for persistedObjectId-field

Comment: What should I `return` by it then?